# Polishing mirror

Tags: mirror-making

While polishing the mirror there is a zone in center become more deep. I tried short center over center strokes while keeping the mirror on the top but it does not resolved. What should I do, should I fine grind mirror again or try tool on top an apply short center over center strokes

Comment: first question, what diameter has your mirror?
Do you work with a full size tool or sub diameter tool?